OpenAI - getting a failed to open stream error on ChatGPT api calls
I have a small script that updates a database table with descriptions generated by ChatGPT.
It worked perfectly for a while, but the started throwing:  PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
in xxx.php on line 77
My API account is funded.
Here is the code:
<?php
// Configuration
$apiKey = 'XXX'; // Replace with your OpenAI API key
$dbHost = 'XXX'; // Database host
$dbUser = 'XXX'; // Database username
$dbPass = 'XXX'; // Database password
$dbName = 'XXX'; // Database name
$tableName = 'XXX'; // Database table
$rateLimitDelay = 5; // Delay between API calls in seconds

// Connect to MySQL
$conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

while (true) {
    // Fetch a single product without a description
    $sqlFetch = "SELECT id_product, product_name FROM $tableName WHERE description IS NULL AND inserted = 0 LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sqlFetch);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $productId = $row['id_product'];
            $productName = $row['product_name'];

            // Call OpenAI API to get a product description
            $description = getOpenAIDescription($productName, $apiKey);

            // Update the description in the database
            if ($description) {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $tableName SET description = ?, inserted = 1 WHERE id_product = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("sii", $description, $productId);
                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    echo "Updated product ID $productId with description: $description\n";
                } else {
                    echo "Failed to update product ID $productId: " . $stmt->error . "\n";
                }
                $stmt->close();
            }

            // Delay to respect rate limits
            sleep($rateLimitDelay);
        }
    } else {
        echo "No more products without descriptions found.\n";
        break;
    }
}

$conn->close();

// Function to call OpenAI API
function getOpenAIDescription($productName, $apiKey)
{
    $url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";

    $data = [
        "model" => "gpt-4", // Specify the model to use
        "messages" => [
            ["role" => "system", "content" => "You are a helpful assistant generating product descriptions for liquor products. You are most interested in back of bottle labels, but will also consider tasting and other information that are descriptive of the product. You will limit the descriptions generated to 200 words, knowing that these descriptions will be used as product descriptions on a liquor website."],
            ["role" => "user", "content" => "Provide a product description for: $productName"]
        ],
        "max_tokens" => 150
    ];

    $options = [
        "http" => [
            "header" => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                        "Authorization: Bearer $apiKey\r\n",
            "method" => "POST",
            "content" => json_encode($data)
        ]
    ];

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    if ($response === FALSE) {
        echo "Error calling OpenAI API.\n";
        return null;
    }

    $responseData = json_decode($response, true);
    if (isset($responseData['choices'][0]['message']['content'])) {
        return trim($responseData['choices'][0]['message']['content']);
    } else {
        echo "Failed to parse OpenAI API response.\n";
        return null;
    }
}


This error code shows the server cannot understand your request or process it correctly. If the code worked before and you have valid account try reducing the size of the prompt. The max_tokens are ok but in the "messages" the "role" => "system", "content" seems too long.
